# How to draw the values produced by a function using PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am wondering how to draw any function using PIL in python on the interval (-1,1). I have started with function `y = x**2` and so far I have this:

```
from PIL import Image

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


def parabola(x):
    return (-1) * (x ** 2)

def draw_function(function, size=200):
    im = Image.new("RGB", (size, size))
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            if function(x)< function(y):
                im.putpixel((x,y), BLACK)
            else:
                im.putpixel((x,y), WHITE)
    im.show()

draw_function(parabola)
```

but I am getting just:

[image]

And I want to get:

[image]

Can you tell me where the problem can be?

Comment: Where did you define `function`? '

Comment: have you tried condition `if function(x) < y:`

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think you're approaching the problem correctly. First, think about what you condition for the pixel to be black means:

```
function(x) < function(y)
```

This doesn't really define the area below the parabola. The condition that does is

```
function(x) < y
```

Also, think about what your plotting area is. It is `[0, 200) x [0, 200)`. Also, in `PIL` the `x` coordinate increases downward in the image, so your parabola will be visible (if at all) upside down.

Here's a little modification to your code:

```
from PIL import Image

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


def parabola(x):
    return (-1) * ((x - 100) ** 2) + 150

def draw_function(function, size=200):
    im = Image.new("RGB", (size, size))
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            if function(x) < y:
                im.putpixel((x,y), BLACK)
            else:
                im.putpixel((x,y), WHITE)
    im.show()

draw_function(parabola)
```

This should produce a picture somewhat resembling this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the `x` and `y` values so they represent coordinates in the range of `0` to `size-1` in order to use them to draw on the `Image`. This is accomplished in the code below by first finding the minimum and maximum values the function will return for `x` values in that range. It then uses those to translate (move) and scale them so they all fall into the needed range. To get the area underneath the curve to be fill-in, you need to draw vertical lines, not individual pixels. To do that I used `ImageDraw.Draw.line()` instead of `im.putpixel()`. The image background is also initialized to `WHITE` in the `Image.new()` call.

Also note that the image produced will be upside-down from what is shown in most textbooks because the origin is the upper left-hand corner, and the y axis runs from the there to the bottom-left. Most illustrations have the origin in the bottom-left. If you wished, you could fix that, too.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

def parabola(x):
    return (-1) * (x ** 2)

def draw_function(function, size=200):
    min_y, max_y = 0, 0
    for x in range(size):
        val = function(x)
        if val < min_y:
            min_y = val
        if val > max_y:
            max_y = val
    delta = max_y - min_y

    im = Image.new("RGB", (size, size), WHITE)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    for x in range(size):
        y = int(((function(x)-min_y) / delta) * (size-1))
        draw.line([(x, 0), (x, y)], BLACK)
    im.show()

draw_function(parabola)
```

Results:

[image: output showing parabola]